# Translating custom validation rule messages in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, validation, translation

I have two possible languages in my Application, `en` and `de`.

I translate it using Localization and json strings.

This is a part of the validation of one field:

```
 if (!empty($value) && (!empty($var1) || empty($var2))) {
    $fail('Hier ist ein deutscher Satz geschrieben.');
 }
```

This is the affiliated json:

```
{
  "Hier ist ein deutscher Satz geschrieben." : "Here is written an english sentence."
}
```

This translation works just fine, but if I have a $value included in a sentence like this:

```
if (!empty($value) && (!empty($var1) || empty($var2))) {
   $fail('Hier ist ein' ".$value." ' deutscher Satz geschrieben');
}
```

... I can't translate it with json anymore, since I can't just split the sentence.
Is there a way I can translate a custom validation rule message with a dynamic variable?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#custom-validation-rules

Comment: @SomeDev This doesn't solve my problem with the $value.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I just put another if-clause inside and check if the $locale of the application is whether `en` or `de`. It's working like that.

```
if (!empty($value) && (!empty($var1) || empty($var2))) {
  if (app()->getLocale() == 'en') {
    $fail('Here is written a "' .$value '" enlgish sentence.);
  } else {
     $fail('Hier ist ein "' .$value. '" deutscher Satz geschrieben');
  }
}
```